# React not rendering background images from function call

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (a function really) that uses a parameter for a background image:

```
const Card = function(image){
    return(
        <div className="card" 
             style={{backgroundImage: 'url(../../static/assets/' + image + ')',
                     backgroundSize: 'cover',
                     backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                     backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>

        </div>
    )
}
```

I call that function like so:

```
const Content = () => {
    return(
        <div className="content">
            {Card("pie-specialty.jpg")}
            {Card("pie-catering2.jpg")}
            {Card("pie-logo.png")}

        </div>
    )
}
```

But only the first and third images actually load.

I have all the images in the same folder, can see them in the folder, checked the spelling, refreshed the folder, nothing happens.

Any ideas on why the second image does not load?

It's also that the first and third images are the only ones to load out of the 6 total images I have in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const Card = function(props){
    return(
        <div className="card" 
             style={{backgroundImage: 'url(../../static/assets/' + props.image + ')',
                     backgroundSize: 'cover',
                     backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                     backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>

        </div>
    )
}


const Content = () => {
    return(
        <div className="content">
            <Card image="pie-specialty.jpg"/>
            <Card image="pie-catering2.jpg"/>
            <Card image="pie-logo.png"/>

        </div>
    )
}
```

You can use the Card component like a JSX element. No need for the {{Card}}

Comment: But now it only shows the last image. Should Card be a class that extends Component as well? Then I should be using properties like you do with objects?